# Clip UILabel to UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, size, uilabel

I am trying to create a `UILabel` inside a `UIImageView` but it doesn't fit correctly into the `UIImageView` bounds. I can set it fine when running in portrait, but when I turn the device to landscape it seems to lose the orientation and it appears outside the `UIImageView`.

Is there some way to clip the `UILabel` into the `UIImageView`?

Comment: try to change label's size (bounds) in change orientation method

Comment: can you please show some code what you've done? you have to set proper Autolayout for that.

Comment: If you are using autolayout then its not necessary to set bound again 
just give constraint to UILabel -> UIImageView that equal width

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by adding appropriate constraints to both your label and imageview. Here's a sample code which fixes your label from left, right and bottom of imageview :

// align yourLabel from the left and right

```
[yourImageview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[yourLabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(yourLabel)]];
```

// align yourLabel from the bottom

```
[yourImageview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[yourLabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(yourLabel)]];
```